# Explain this snort rule

Tags: snort

Please explain the following Snort rule. Describe the meanings of all the options and modifiers used in the rule

alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $SQL_SERVERS 1433 (msg:"Attack Detected"; flow:to_server,established; content:"|02|";depth:1;content:"sa";depth:2;offset:39; nocase; detection_filter:track_by_src,count 5,seconds 2;)

Comment: You don't provide any context of this rule (what should it detect?) and you don't explain what exactly you don't understand, which make any explanation a guess on what you might want to know, i.e. if this is the thing you did not understand and if the level of detail is sufficient for you to understand.  It is not even clear what knowledge of snort rules you already have and where one needs to start with the explanation. This makes this question too broad.

Comment: This is the only thing on my screen at the time and I don't understand what it means. That's all the context I have for myself-hence why I'm asking what it means.

Comment: But without us knowing what your baseline understanding is how can we begin to explain it. There are whole books on snort...

Comment: I just need the meanings of the options and modifiers explained to me

Comment: @penceyreject: *"I just need the meanings of the options and modifiers explained to me"* - in other words: you are either unable to find [the documentation](https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/178/original/snort_manual.pdf), to lazy to read it or unable to understand it. In the first two cases you should have tried harder yourself. In the last case please ask specific questions on what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Snort rule syntax is provided in the Snort documentation. Please read the documentation and then edit your question with the parts you did not understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn all of these things by reading the [manual](https://snort-org-site.s3.amazonaws.com/production/document_files/files/000/000/178/original/snort_manual.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA%2F20190819%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20190819T213504Z&X-Amz-Expires=172800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=464806dd2327591cd7194ea3b9ebde99590f611c12e8bbdada912f69133b47ac).

```
alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $SQL_SERVERS 1433
```

Give a yell if you see a TCP packet *from* what I've defined as external networks going *to* what I've defined as SQL Servers on port 1433.

```
(msg:"Attack Detected";
```

When you yell, say "Attack Detected"

```
flow:to_server,established;
```

Only yell if the SQL Server is the TCP "server" in this connection, and that this TCP connection has been nailed up (e.g., ignore random packets that aren't part of a connection).

```
content:"|02|";depth:1;
```

Only yell if you also find a binary 0x02 character within the first 1 byte of the message.

```
content:"sa";depth:2;offset:39; nocase;
```

Only yell if you also find the string "sa" (or "SA", or "Sa", or "sA") in the two bytes after the 39th byte of the packet.

```
detection_filter:track_by_src,count 5,seconds 2;)
```

Only yell if you also happen to see 5 packets matching this criteria within 2 seconds.